# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 2]

Tags: python, pandas, regression, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Here is my block of code:

```
x_train = []
def preprocess_dataset(batch_size, normalize=True):
    #first accessing RSSI columns to train x-axis
    col_list = [0, 1]
    trainX_data_frame = pd.read_csv('/home/Documents/generated_rssi_dataset.csv', usecols=col_list)
    trainX_rows = pd.DataFrame(trainX_data_frame)
    for trainX_row in trainX_rows:
        train_x1 = trainX_row.loc[0]
        #train_x1 = trainX_row[0].loc[trainX_row]
        train_x2 = trainX_row.loc[1]
        training_x = ((train_x1 + train_x2)/2)
        x_train = x_train.append(training_x) 
    return np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

for i in range(training_cycles):
    x_train = preprocess_dataset(x_train)
    y_train = preprocess_dataset(np.array(y_train))
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train, time_steps, n_features)
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=10,validation_split=0.2)
```

[image]

I am getting an attribute error caused by a named error. I have checked the other parts of the code, it is not missing any declarations or definitions anywhere. Only in this part of the code 'the function preprocess_dataset' has some error. I understand it is due to the for loop, the possibility is that if the loop isn't executed then x_train won't have any attribute. But I don't know how to resolve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: y_train is a similar block so I have not added it here in the code section.

%%%%%% update 4th July 2021%%%%
using comment by Nicolas Gervais, changed the below.

```
x_train = []
y_train = []

def preprocess_dataset_x(batch_size, normalize=True):
    #first accessing RSSI columns to train x-axis
    col_list_x = [0, 1]
    trainX_data_frame = pd.read_csv('/home/kobuki/Documents/generated_rssi_dataset.csv', usecols=col_list_x)
    trainX_rows = pd.DataFrame(trainX_data_frame)
    for index, row in trainX_rows.iterrows():
        train_x1 = trainX_rows.loc[0]
        train_x2 = trainX_rows.loc[1]
        training_x = ((train_x1 + train_x2)/2)
        x_train.append(training_x)
    print("x_train calculated and stored in array")
    return np.array(x_train)    

def preprocess_dataset_y(batch_size, normalize=True):
    #accessing loc coordinates to train y-axis
    col_list_y = [2, 3]
    trainY_data_frame = pd.read_csv('/home/kobuki/Documents/generated_rssi_dataset.csv', usecols = col_list_y)
    trainY_rows = pd.DataFrame(trainY_data_frame)
    for index, row in trainY_rows.iterrows():
        train_y1 = trainY_rows.loc[2]
        train_y2 = trainY_rows.loc[3]
        training_y = (train_y1, train_y2)
        y_train.append(training_y)
    print("y_train calculated and stored in array")
    return np.array(y_train)

for i in range(training_cycles):
    x_train = preprocess_dataset_x(np.array(x_train))
    y_train = preprocess_dataset_y(np.array(y_train))
    ### x_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
    ### y_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train)
    ### x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train, time_steps, n_features)
    ### y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train, time_steps, n_features)
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=10)
```

after this point, while fitting the model to a conv1D I am getting the below error now.

[image]

I am getting errors with reshaping also and the array created along x_train, y_train is 460, 460, 2. I don't know why it says min_ndim expected as 3. Please advise.

%%% Model %%%

```
def createCnnLstmModel(time_steps, n_features):
    ##CorNet architecture
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',input_shape=(time_steps, n_features)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',input_shape=(time_steps, n_features)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(LSTM(128,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(128,activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='RMSProp',loss='MAE',metrics=['mae','mape',soft_acc])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

timesteps = 460 and n_features are 2.

Comment: What's the output of `print(trainX_row)` at the very beginning of the loop in `preprocess_dataset`?

Comment: you need `df.iterrows()` which return index, row to iterate through a dataframe

Comment: @ForceBru It did print the first element of trainX_row.

Comment: @vasudha, what _is_ that element? Is it a string?

Comment: @ForceBru It is int but that is cleared now. I have updated with the recent changes where i am getting value error. Please check and advise.

Comment: What is the shape of `x_train` and `y_train` which you are using with `model.fit()` ?

Comment: @Kishore shape of `x_train` is (459, 2) and shape of `y_train` is (459, 2, 2).

Comment: How does training features (x_train) have lesser dimensions compared to labels (y_train) ?  Could you add your model to the description ?

Comment: @Kishore I have added my model to the description. If i do not take average values in `preprocess_dataset` then `x_train` shape will also be 459, 2, 2. But then after both the convolutions, there is negative dimension. (ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 2). I have 2 AP's RSSI data in column 0 and column 1. My output should be x, y coordinates of location which is on column 2 and column 3. I took average values of both RSSI first, but due to the shaping error i ignored the average as there is not much of a difference.

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` expects input shape 3D Tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`.  Modify your x_train such that it should be 3D. Thanks!